# Excel File set to UTF-8

Tags: excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I´ve developed an application in C#, which adjusts logfiles. Special information from a given logfile will be put together to a new csv file.

Writing in the first line of the CSV file "sep=\t" causes that Excel uses the tab as seperator and not the comma.

Is there anything similiar so that my generated Excel file will automatically be encoded with UTF-8?

One solution is that I set my StreamWriter to Encoding.Unicode.

But then in the first line of my Excelfile "sep=" is shown.

Earlier without that configuration the line was hidden.

What can I do that both is fulfilled. The tab as seperator and Unicode as encoding.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is generated while importing `UTF-8` encoded file in Excel. Please look into it , if it is useful to you.My file in this reference is `ALKEM` which need to be changed.<https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtwhk39hbm3pjkc/55139910-excel-file-set-to-utf-8.docx?dl=0>

Comment: I wouldn't call a CSV file an Excel file. Consider writing an .xlsx or equivalent file anyway because it avoids needing to keep, communicate and use all the required metadata (character encoding, column data type, …, …) that's external for a CSV file.

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft is very used to put BOM marks everywere. Possibly adding a BOM will solve the problem (but as you see in this site, it causes a lot problems when importing files in R and other tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sep=\t" has to be in Quotes.

```
 csvwriter.WriteToFileSingleString("\"sep=\t\"");
```